# Coupling global dashboard filters and filter-only dimensions in Looker

Tags: google-cloud-platform, looker, lookml

I have a dashboard that utilizes filter-only date dimensions to compare two ranges (`base` and `comparison`). I also have a more general global date filter which, for my dashboard use case, is redundant. I would like to have the global date filter use the filter-only dimensions in a dashboard.

The filters included are as follows:

- `event_date` - a date dimension implemented as a filter on the dashboard (which I would like to remove)
- base range date filter (`dt_a`) - a filter applied to measures used for comparison
- comparison range date filter (`dt_b`) - a filter applied to measures compared to base measures

The dimensions and filters are defined as follows:

```sql
# Global calendar date
dimension: event_date {
    sql: ${TABLE}.event_date ;;
  }

# Filters and filter-only dimensions
filter: dt_a {
    label: "Date filter (base)"
    type: date
  }
  dimension: group_a_yesno {
    hidden: yes
    type: yesno
    sql: {% condition dt_a %} timestamp(${event_date}) {% endcondition %} ;;
  }

  filter: dt_b {
    label: "Date filter (comp)"
    type: date
  }
  dimension: group_b_yesno {
    hidden: yes
    type: yesno
    sql:  {% condition dt_b %} timestamp(${event_date}) {% endcondition %} ;;
  }
```

I have explored liquid parameters in the table definition as well as filter setting in the dashboard itself.

Ideally, I would like the `date_filter_base` and `date_filter_comp` to be read into the `event_date` filter applied to the broader query where the `WHERE` clause reads the filters applied to each of the measures `view_count_a` and `view_count_b`.

For example, comparing two `count_distinct` measures whose date filters are used in as `OR`:

```sql
select
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ((( timestamp(view.event_date) ) >= (TIMESTAMP('2023-11-20 00:00:00')) AND ( timestamp(view.event_date) ) < (TIMESTAMP('2023-11-25 00:00:00')))) THEN ga4_view_bq.user_pseudo_id ELSE NULL END) AS view_count_a,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ((( timestamp(view.event_date) ) >= (TIMESTAMP('2023-11-27 00:00:00')) AND ( timestamp(view.event_date) ) < (TIMESTAMP('2023-12-02 00:00:00')))) THEN view.user_pseudo_id ELSE NULL END) AS view_count_b,
from ...
where
    ((( timestamp(view.event_date) ) >= (TIMESTAMP('2023-11-20 00:00:00')) AND ( timestamp(view.event_date) ) < (TIMESTAMP('2023-11-25 00:00:00'))) OR
    ((( timestamp(view.event_date) ) >= (TIMESTAMP('2023-11-27 00:00:00')) AND ( timestamp(view.event_date) ) < (TIMESTAMP('2023-12-02 00:00:00')))
;
```

Is there a way to implement this in LookML?

Answer (score 0):

LookML is pretty flexible and you can acheive it depending on what you want. Answer lies in date type parameter of type datetime. Start with defining different parameters for base and comparison dates (Used 4 for better control)

```
  parameter: base_date_start {
    type: date_time
    description: "Start Date of Base"
  }
  
  parameter: base_date_end {
    type: date_time
    description: "End Date for Base"
  }
  
  parameter: comp_date_start {
    type: date_time
    description: "Start Date of Comparison"
  }
  
  parameter: comp_date_end {
    type: date_time
    description: "End date of Comparison"
  }

  dimension: event_date {
    type: date
    hidden: yes
    sql: ${TABLE}."DATE" ;;
  }
```

And now you can define independent filters to be applied to `event_date` (which can be removed from dashboard or very well set to be hidden now):

```
  filter: base_filter {
   type: yesno
   sql: ${event_date} between {% parameter base_date_start %} and {% parameter base_date_end %} ;;
  }

  filter: comp_filter {
   type: yesno
   sql: ${event_date} between {% parameter comp_date_start %} and {% parameter comp_date_end %} ;;
  }

  filter: base_or_comp_filter {
    type: yesno
    sql: ${comp_filter} OR ${base_filter} ;;
  }
```

Which in turn can be applied to measures as follows:

```
  measure: base_measure {
    type: sum
     sql: ${TABLE}.YOUR_COLUMN;;
     filters: [base_filter: "yes"]
  }

  measure: comp_measure {
    type: sum
     sql: ${TABLE}.YOUR_COLUMN;;
     filters: [comp_filter: "yes"]
  }

  measure: measure_valid_for_base_or_comp_ranges {
    type: sum
     sql: ${TABLE}.YOUR_COLUMN ;;
     filters: [base_or_comp_filter : "yes"]
}
```

When all three measures are selected in a visualization and parameters above selected as:
[image]

SQL generated as follows:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN ( ((TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(temp_test_datetime_params."DATE" ), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) between TO_TIMESTAMP('2023-11-27') and TO_TIMESTAMP('2023-12-02')) OR ((TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(temp_test_datetime_params."DATE" ), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) between TO_TIMESTAMP('2023-11-20') and TO_TIMESTAMP('2023-11-25')) ) THEN temp_test_datetime_params.YOUR_COLUMN ELSE NULL END), 0) AS "temp_test_datetime_params.measure_valid_for_base_or_comp_ranges",
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN ( (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(temp_test_datetime_params."DATE" ), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) between TO_TIMESTAMP('2023-11-27') and TO_TIMESTAMP('2023-12-02') ) THEN temp_test_datetime_params.OUR_COLUMN ELSE NULL END), 0) AS "temp_test_datetime_params.comp_measure",
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN ( (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(temp_test_datetime_params."DATE" ), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) between TO_TIMESTAMP('2023-11-20') and TO_TIMESTAMP('2023-11-25') ) THEN temp_test_datetime_params.OUR_COLUMN ELSE NULL END), 0) AS "temp_test_datetime_params.base_measure"
FROM "YOUR_SCHEMA"."YOUR_TABLE" AS temp_test_datetime_params
```

If you want to apply them everywhere consider using `always_filter` in your explore and utilize these filters accordingly.

Comment: thanks @hamza—the part that this is still missing is that the generated sql WHERE clause that takes the same date params as the filters that you defined here. what i'm looking for is a way to use the same dates/filters that are being used for base and comp for the query level filter (WHERE clause) so that a user only has to define the date filters once.

right now those will have to be defined separately (total of six date filters applied rather than four: min & max for base/comp).

Comment: For that you can just define min_filter and max_filters using same logic and add them to the measures